# Twillio IP Messaging Notification - Channel Settings

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, twilio, messaging

I'm mainly reaching out to the Twilio team active on here  and for the benefit of the community.

Our team will is looking to implement Twilio IP Messaging to fulfill our app messaging requirements. One of the use cases we'd like to handle is the ability for a user to turn off notifications for a specific channel. I don't see anything in the docs that speak to this, so we could of course implement the logic on our servers. But, I don't see the ability for a pre-event callback for something like `onNotificationSend` to check if a notification should go to the user. I don't want to use [`onMessageSend`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/webhooks#pre-callbacks) since the message should still go out, just not the notification.

My other thought would be to intercept the notification in the app and check our app state to see if that channel is able to receive notifications. Reading the docs for iOS notifications, it looks like I can determine what to do with notifications outside of the app being open, I just wanted to check if that was the best/only option for this scenario.

Thanks in advance for any help.

-Brad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the opportunity to talk to the Product Manager for IP Messaging at the Signal conference, and he said the ability to mute channel notifications is in the road map. So I think I'll wait to implement something until that comes GA.

Comment: Hey Brad, Did you find any way to mute specific channel notification?

Comment: @parth not that I recall. I'm no longer working for the org that was going to use this, but did a quick docs check and it doesn't look like anything has been provided to mute a channel.